# Saving JComboBoxes values to Text File

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am making a small gui in which i read data from text file to different JComboBoxes,user edits in JComboBoxes and then save it in new text file.My new file gets saved but not in the format from were it read.
Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class A extends JPanel 
{
public A() {

JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
add(buttonPanel);
buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10));


JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox();
combo1.addItem("1ms");
combo1.addItem("2ms");
buttonPanel.add(combo1);

JComboBox combo2 = new JComboBox();
combo2.addItem("1ms");
combo2.addItem("2ms");
buttonPanel.add(combo2);

JComboBox combo3 = new JComboBox();
combo3.addItem("1ms");
combo3.addItem("2ms");
buttonPanel.add(combo3);

JComboBox combo4 = new JComboBox();
combo4.addItem("1ms");
combo4.addItem("2ms");
buttonPanel.add(combo4);


JComboBox[] fieldBoxs = new JComboBox[4];
fieldBoxs[0] = combo1;
    fieldBoxs[1] = combo2;
    fieldBoxs[2] = combo3;
    fieldBoxs[3] = combo4;


ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

final StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

try{
    InputStream ips=new FileInputStream("test.txt");
        InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);

            String line;
    boolean found = false;

        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
        String[] s = line.split(" ");
        list.add(s[0]);
        list.add(s[1]);
if (s[0].equals("0") && !found)
    {
        found = true;
        temp.append(line).append("\r\n");
    }
    else if (found)
    {
        temp.append(line).append("\r\n");
    } 
    }
br.close(); 
    }       
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

for(int i = 0; i < fieldBoxs.length; i++) {
    fieldBoxs[i].setSelectedItem(list.get(i));
}

JButton button = new JButton("SAVE");
buttonPanel.add(button);
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

     try { 
            StringBuilder con = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldBoxs.length; i++) 

                   {
                    Object Value = fieldBoxs[i].getSelectedItem();
                    con.append(" ");
            con.append(Value);
            con.append("\r\n");
           }

    FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(new File("A.txt"));
    filewriter.write(con.append(temp).toString());
        filewriter.flush();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
A app = new A();
JFrame m = new JFrame("A");
m.getContentPane().add(app);
m.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
m.pack();
m.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

This is the file from were i am reading the values:test

```
 2ms 1ms
 1ms 2ms
 0 0
 1 2
 2 1
 1 1
 2 2
```

This is how my file is saved now:

```
 2ms
 1ms
 1ms
 2ms
 0 0
 1 2
 2 1
 1 1
 2 2
```

I would like to save it as:

```
 2 1
 1 2
 0 0
 1 2
 2 1
 1 1
 2 2
```

The format should be same as the format from where it is reading and ms also should not appear in the new saved text file.
Any help would be truly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little bit of code which would format your example correctly. I don't recommend using this code if its for work or used long term because it isn't flexible or nice.

```
    String[] cons = con.split("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < cons.length; i++){
        if(i == 0 || i == 2){
            cons[i] = cons[i] + " ";
        }else{
           cons[i] = cons[i] + "\n"; 
        }
       }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : cons) {
        builder.append(s);
    }
    con = builder.toString();¨
```

Basically the code iterates through the different lines of the con string (removes the lineseperator with the split) and adds a new one only if its not line 0 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
JButton button = new JButton("SAVE");
buttonPanel.add(button);
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

     try { 

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("A.txt"));
        out.print(fieldBoxs[0].getSelectedItem());
        out.print(" ");
        out.print(fieldBoxs[1].getSelectedItem());
        out.println();
        out.print(fieldBoxs[2].getSelectedItem());
        out.print(" ");
        out.print(fieldBoxs[3].getSelectedItem());
        out.println();
        out.print(temp);        
        out.close();    
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```